# Оптимально создать заполненный массив

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм, оптимизация, code-hunt

Добрые сутки!

Решил поиграть на [Microsoft Research (Code Hunt)](https://www.codehunt.com), не могу выполнить задачу на 3 звезды, только одну получаю. Не понимаю, почему мой код считается не оптимальным.

Суть задачи в том, что приходит натуральное число, нужно создать массив указанной размерности заполненный с 0 до размера массива.

Сделал код:

```
using System;
public class Program {
    public static int[] Puzzle(int n) {
        var arr = new int[n];
        for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Оценка его 1 звезда (ну то есть правильно, но не очень). Пробовал заполнять его за один проход с двух сторон (ну то есть с i элемента и n-i элемента), но результат все равно оставался таким же. Вариант начала цикла с 1, а не с 0, тоже не пройдет.

В общем я не знаю как его еще оптимизировать. Подскажите, где я провалился?

Comment: Они там любят LINQ попробуй примерно так:
public static int[] Puzzle(int n) {
         var t = new int[n];
  t.ToList().ForEach(a=>t[n-1]= --n);
  return t;
    }

Comment: @gost, нет, тоже 1 звезда.

Comment: @gost, может в шарпе есть секретная комбинация объявлять сразу инициализированный массив? В некоторых языках есть такое объявление, но в шарпе не сталкивался, в msdn в примерах тоже не встречал.

Comment: return new int[n].Select(a=>a=(n--)-1).ToArray<int>();

Comment: @gost, чтобы результат был правильным немного изменил на:

    return new int[n].Select(a=>(n--)-1).Reverse().ToArray<int>();

но все равно 1 звезда. Мне кажется тут linq не в тему :-)

Comment: А так можно?
 public static IEnumerable Puzzle(int n) 
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
            yield return i;
        }
 }

Comment: @gost, нет, менять основной статик метод нельзя. Менять можно только внутренности и создавать вспомогательные методы.

Comment: @VladD, Да, за это решение 3 звезды дали. Можете оформить как ответ, чтобы я мог принять?

Comment: @pincher1519: конечно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эффективнее всего вручную через цикл, понятно. Лаконичнее всего `Enumerable.Range(0, n)`. (Если нужен именно массив, то `.ToArray()` в конце.)

Comment: А про слона мы и забыли... ни разу в жизни не пользовал этот метод :)

Comment: @gost, я про него и не знал. Как по мне, вообще сомнительное практическое имеет данный метод. Но знать полезно...